How to install a large number of packages in parallel while initializing a Conda environment via YAML?
environment.yaml contains several dozen dependencies and uses the conda-forge channel. When I create my new Conda environment using conda env create -f environment.yaml, the process is extremely slow due to the large number of packages being installed. Is there a way to install the packages in parallel to speed things up?
I tried adding the option --j16 to the end of conda env create -f environment.yaml, but that didn't work.

try using mamba, but apart from that i don't know of any speedup options

Disk IO and file system operations are probably a big bottleneck here, so parallelization will only give limited speedup. I do know that mamba parallelizes extracting of packages
